# How Can I Get a Google Calendar and an Outlook (Online) Calendar to *Stay* In Sync?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar, outlook.com-calendar

I can import my Google Calendar into Outlook (the online version, not the desktop software).  I can also do the reverse.  But either way when I do, it only updates *at the moment I add the calendar*.  If I add a new event to (say) the Google Calendar afterwards, it doesn't show up in Outlook until about a day later.  The same is true in reverse (adding to Outlook takes a day-ish to show up in Google).

Neither service has any sort of "force sync" feature (that I can find  at least) ... but syncing is useless if I can't see new entries from one calendar, inside the other, in a timely fashion.

There must be thousands of people using both services, so there has to be *some* way to get them sync *properly* (i.e. faster than a day) ... but I can't figure out how.  How does everyone use both services together without having to check two calendars?

Comment: Nowadays [tag:calendar] is a meta-tag on this site, it should not be used.

Comment: Where does the link you provided (or anywhere else) say that?  To the contrary, the link **explicitly says** "Questions in this tag are related to web applications with calendar features, such as Google Calendar."

Comment: Look at [meta].

Comment: That's not how Stack Exchange sites work.  You don't get to just make up rules and then tell people to dig through a million meta posts to find your made-up rule.  If there was a serious effort to change the tag's usage, the *first* thing anyone should do is edit its description.